# how to update the values in config file

Tags: linux, shell

I have an Config.yml file i want to update the values like below by using shell script.

current file data

servers:
  - uri: http://localhost:5550/service/mgmt/current
  - displayName: server1
  - username: user
  - password: welcome
  - domains:
  --- default
  --- domain1
  - useBulkApi: true

Required out put should be like below:
servers:
  - uri: https://hostname1:5550/service/mgmt/current
  - displayName: instance1
  - username: xx
  - password: xx
  - domains:
  --- default
  --- domain1
  - useBulkApi: true

hostname, user, password and domain name will changes for each URI. These values coming script. I have to update at lease 3 server details and each server has different URI, hostname, user, password and domain

Comment: Why don't you use [`envsubst`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst) from `gettext-base` package (Ubuntu)? You could create a template file any format you like and then process it with `envsubst` and environment variables you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have use the sed command to edit the files. 
Assuming four argument is passed to you script,

```
1. URI
2. Username
3. Password
4. Domains
```

can do something like this:

```
sed -i 's/: http:\/\/localhost:5550\/service\/mgmt\/current$/$1/' Config.yml
sed -i 's/: user$/$2/' Config.yml
sed -i 's/: welcome$/$3/' Config.yml
sed -i 's/: domain1$/$4/' Config.yml
```

Also, instead of having four command, you can write this in a single command using -e option of sed.

Small suggestion: Instead of having default value for all the parameter's in you're file, you can do something like this

```
servers:
- uri: <URI>
- displayName: server1
- username: <USER>
- password: <PASSWORD>
- domains:
--- default
--- <DOMAIN>
- useBulkApi: true
```

Using placeholder like this, will ensure that you replace correct option

Above sed command will be modified as follows:

sed -i 's//$1/' Config.yml

More information on sed can be found [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/unix-sed-tutorial-replace-text-inside-a-file-using-substitute-command/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20TheGeekStuff%20(The%20Geek%20Stuff))

Yes you can use a loop. You can create let's say 2 file having same content and dynamically change file name to edit this files. 
Or else, you can simply redirect output of sed command to create new files. Below is  an example for redirecting two files

```
sed 's/: http:\/\/localhost:5550\/service\/mgmt\/current$/$1/' -e  's/: user$/$2/' -e 's/: welcome$/$3/' -e 's/: domain1$/$4/' Config.yml > ServerDetail1.yml

sed 's/: http:\/\/localhost:5550\/service\/mgmt\/current$/$1/' -e  's/: user$/$2/' -e 's/: welcome$/$3/' -e 's/: domain1$/$4/' Config.yml > ServerDetail2.yml
```

Comment: If i want to add another server details also, my requirement is to configure more than one server. is it possible to for loop function

Comment: my case i have only one file. i want to append the server details like belowservers:
uri: https://hostname1:5550/service/mgmt/current - displayName: instance1 - username: xx - password: xx- domains: --- default--- domain1- useBulkApi: true
uri: https://Hostname2:5550/service/mgmt/current - displayName: instance1 - username: xx - password: xx- domains: --- default--- domain1- useBulkApi: true
uri: https://hostname3:5550/service/mgmt/current - displayName: instance1 - username: xx - password: xx- domains: --- default--- domain1- useBulkApi: true

Comment: I hope you understand the requirement.. Thanks for ur reply

Comment: Go through the documentation of sed. I think, sed is the command which will help you. There is a sed option 'a' which appends lines based on given pattern